# display some data and a details button to show details

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

```
<td> <?php echo $n['notice']; ?> </td>
```

Here `$n['notice']` contains  message.

How can I show some sentences and a details button to show details of the message.

Comment: above code is in the listing of the table? Need to display the full message on a new page or same page?

Comment: yes in a table. need to display in the same page @MohsinMarui

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution using jQuery.

Update your **HTML** as below

```
    <td>
           <?php echo substr($n['notice'],0,15);?> <a class="showdetail" href="javascript:void(0)">Show More<b></a>
            <div class="details"><?php echo $n['notice']?></div>
    </td>
```

**CSS** code for set details message div to `display:none` as below. You can add below line in your existing CSS or add this CSS into your page with `<style></style>` tag.

```
.details{display: none;}
```

put below **jQuery** code on your table listing page make sure javascript library loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $('.showdetail').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('td').find(".details").toggle();
    });
});
```